# how to move sprite with delay in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

i have number of sprite in array. now i want to moving that sprite with delay time 0.5.i am use below code at that time all sprite are fall at same time but i want to falling the sprite one by one.i am also use CCDelay method but also not get required result.

```
for (int j = 1; j < [ary count]; j++)
 {
    torpedoOne.position = ccp(160,580);

    id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0
                                        position:ccp(30 + (j*25),300)];

    id deleay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0];


    [torpedoOne runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove,deleay,nil]];

    [self addChild:torpedoOne];

 }
```

first of all for loop is complete after the action is run so that all sprite has same acion with same time.

how can i run action when each time go in for loop?

i am aslo try [COCOS2D: how to animate falling bricks into a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631172/cocos2d-how-to-animate-falling-bricks-into-a-grid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time,i got one by one with sprite with animation by particular delay in cocos2d .

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),
                       ^{
                              for (int j = 1; j < [ary count]; j++)
                                {
                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                   ^{

                                     torpedoOne.position = ccp(160,580);

                                     id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0
                                            position:ccp(30 + (j*25),300)];

                                     id deleay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1.0];


                                     [torpedoOne runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove,deleay,nil]];

                                     [self addChild:torpedoOne];

                                     });

                                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:delay];

                                }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you logic is weird. Try

```
for (int j = 0;j<[ary count]; j++{        // gets all objects in ary : 0 to count-1
    torpedoOne = [ary objectAtIndex:j];   // I am assuming this is what you wanted

    torpedoOne.position = ccp(160,580);
    id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0
                                        position:ccp(30 + (j*25),300)];
    float delayTime = j*0.5f;
    torpedoOne.visible = NO;
    id show = [CCShow action];   // if you want them invisible prior to start move
    id delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:delayTime];
    [torpedoOne runAction:[CCSequence actions:delay,show,actionMove,nil]];
}
```

also, you should set torpedoOne inside the loop.